# Removing components from the DOM in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3

I am rendering some components using Vue.js (version 3.x)

```
<div v-for="(i, index) in fields" >
    <my-component :id="index" ></my-component>
    <span class="delete-icon" @click="removeField(index)" >&times;</span>
</div>
```

Where `fields` is simply an array like so: `[0,1,2,3,4,...]`

Vue renders as many components as there are elements in `fields` along with the spans having the `delete-icon` which have an event listener to fire the `removeField()` function, which takes the index of the rendered component and is meant to be used to remove the respective component from the DOM.

However, I am not sure how to indicate to Vue that a *specific* component needs to be removed - in other words, how do I tell Vue to remove the particular component who's delete icon I click, as opposed to just deleting an element from the `fields` array, which will re-render the set with one less component, always resulting in the last component being removed.

I am passing unique `id`'s to the components as well, so I technically can remove the components using vanilla JS, but wondering whether Vue offers a more elegant solution.

Comment: you need to `key` the iteration and remove the correct item from the `fields` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that will filter the `fields`

**It is not recommended to use `index` as a unique key.**

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-glitter-5hx9x?file=/src/App.vue:356-477)

```
removeField(index) {
      this.fields = this.fields.filter((number, i) => {
        return i !== index;
      });
    },
```

Comment: The key doesn't need to be a UUID. Any unique key in the context of the `v-for` model would do.

Comment: Just in case, there is [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/removing-components-3qpgl?file=/src/App.vue) of composition API.